# CSS Media query not working when testing in chrome

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

My CSS media query is not working.

```
.container-fluid {
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

@media (min-height: 500px) {
  .container-fluid {
    background-color: green;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
}
```

I have also included

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in the head section

Could you find out anything I did wrong here

Really appreciate if anyone could help

Comment: Hey KoooPooo
I really want to assist you, so can you tell me are you using bootstrap in your HTML?

Comment: Hi @ashutosh, it's so kind of you. I am not using bootstrap in this code snippet

Answer (score 2):

Your style is supposed to be working. You might be confusing `min-height` and `max-height`

If you want the style to change when the view has been resized down to 400px or less use `max-height: 400px` and if you want to change the style when the view has been resized above 400px then use `min-height: 400px`

**However**

If your using a css library that is making use of `.container-fluid` your selector is actually working but it cannot overide the existing style, to fix this you can either do one of the ( or all of it ) following:

1. The `un-neat` way, adding `!important` in your properties.
2. Putting your css `after` the css library has been loaded so your css has higher priority. So `<link href="LIBRARY FIRST"/> then <link href="your css"/>`
3. Using the exact same selector the library used instead of using just `.container-fluid {  }`, sometimes it's written as `.something .something-2 .container-fluid {  }`. In CSS the longer the selector is the more priority it gets.

Here is a working example: Try to resize your browser

```
body {
  height: 100vw;
  width: 100vh;

  background-color: red;
  border:2px solid blue;
}

@media (min-height: 400px) {

  body {
    background-color: green;
    border:2px solid black;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/masterpreenz/efxuw7mg/4/

hope that helps

Comment: Hi Masterpreenz, thank you so much for the help. your code definitely works, but @media doesn't work when i change height to width, do you have any idea why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `!important`.if you override existing bootstrap class

```
.container-fluid{
    background-color: red !important;
    border:2px solid blue !important;
}
@media(min-height:500px){
.container-fluid{
     background-color: green !important;
    border:2px solid black !important;
    }
}
```

or if you don't want to use `!important` try this let's assume you want to apply `@media` to `div`

```
<div class="container-fluid new-fluid"></div>
```

you can use the following css

```
.new-fluid{
    background-color: red;
    border:2px solid blue;
}
@media(min-height:500px){
    .new-fluid{
    background-color: green;
    border:2px solid black;
}
}
```

let me know if this worked

Comment: Hi Vignesh, Thank you so much for the help! I tried but still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried height it works, but it didn't work in width. i am quite confused why is that

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on height then your code is working , Please check below code
which is working on chrome

```css
.container-fluid {
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 200px;
}

@media(min-height:500px) {
  .container-fluid {
    background-color: green;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">my div</div>
```

Comment: Hi Dinesh, Thank you so much for inspiring me!

Comment: do you know why it works on height and not working on width ?

Comment: You have to write @media for width